# Using the "existence" of a list item as an if-statement conditional with Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, exists

I have a program in Python3 where I take values and append them to 1 of two lists (I sort certain values into a certain list). Then I want to do something like this (just an example using the 1st item from the lists):

```
if list1[0] and list2[0] exist:
    #do something using both lists
else:
    if list1[0] exists:
        #do something using just the first list
    else:
        #do something using just the second list
```

It's supposed to be a backup: in case I dont get a value for both the lists, I want to just use the value from the first list. Then, if I don't have an item from the first list, I use the second list. So what I'm asking is: how do I test if an item in a list 'EXISTS'?

Comment: Does `0` stand for a certain key, or is it really just a number?  That is, are you going to use just the first list only when the second list is completely empty?  **PS** Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about how things run around here.

Comment: I guess the other good question I should ask is --- how do you define nonexistence? ;)  If you sort a value into `list1`, do you put `None` or another corresponding element into `list2`?  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45065447/edit) to add a bit more detail ([help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if element of specific index is in the list you can check if `index < len(list1)`. (assuming index is a non negative integer)

```
if index < len(list1) and index < len(list2):
    #do something using both lists
elif index < len(list1):
    #do something using just the first list
elif index < len(list2):
    #do something using just the second list
```

If you want to check whether element of specific value is in the list you will use `if value in list1`.

```
if value in list1 and value in list2:
    #do something using both lists
elif value in list1:
    #do something using just the first list
elif value in list2:
    #do something using just the second list
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the lengths of the lists.

```
if len(list1) > 0 and len(list2) > 0:
    # do something using both lists
elif len(list1) > 0:
    # do something using just the first list
else:
    # do something using just the second list
```

If you're looking specifically for the first element, you can shorten this to:

```
if list1 and list2:
    # do something using both lists
elif list1:
    # do something using just the first list
else:
    # do something using just the second list
```

Evaluating a list in a boolean context checks if the list is non-empty.

Comment: last else should be an `elif len(list2) > 0`, in case both are empty

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if `list[n]` exists, use `if len(list) > n`. List indexes are always consecutive, and never skip, so it works.